# JMS message re-delivery

Tags: java, rabbitmq, jms, activemq-classic, messaging

I have a queue with one producer and two consumers using `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`. The two consumers share the connections, but they live in different threads so each uses its own session.

What happens if consumer A does not acknowledge the last message received? In which scenario the message will be re-delivered and consumed by consumer B? Is it when the session consumer A is using is closed? Do I need some configuration on JMS provider to dictate what happens in such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this situation is directly addressed in the JMS specification so the answer will ultimately depend on what JMS broker you're using. However, having worked on multiple JMS brokers in the past I would say that generally speaking any message that has been dispatched by the broker to a consumer but which hasn't yet been acknowledged by that consumer will be cancelled back to the broker and will be made available for redelivery once the consumer in question is closed.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for your time, I think that's indeed the case when talking about consumers created from the same session, my question is more about consumers one of each using a different session, does this make sense to you ?

Comment: Why would it matter whether or not the consumers were created from the same session or not? As soon as the consumer is closed any non-acknowledged messages should be put back onto the queue for delivery to any other consumer.

Comment: cause I'm just trying with ActiveMQ and it's re-delivered only in the case of cosumers sharing the same session.

Comment: Important details like that should really be part of the question. Please modify your question and elaborate on your *exact* use-case including code where possible. Also, if you're using ActiveMQ why did you tag the question with `rabbitmq`?